# Octopus merge: cosmetic, or indispensible in some cases?

Tags: git

I can do an octopus merge of branches `A` and `B` into `HEAD`.  Or, I can do an ordinary merge of `A`, followed by an ordinary merge of `B`, and if there are no conflicts end up with the same content.  So is the use of octopus really a matter of taste in how the commit history will look, or are there conflicts that are more easily resolved via octopus?

Comment: I never do Octopus merges; too much to untangle if something goes wrong, for too little advantage. Offhand, I can't think of any cases where it would be indispensable. Maybe in some automated environment of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

> is the use of octopus really a matter of taste in how the commit history will look

No. 2 sources in your case isn't good sample: imagine 10-20-30 branches, which you must to merge into mainline, and calculate amount of merges. **Single** advantage of OM - it can merge any amount of sources in one operation

> are there conflicts that are more easily resolved via octopus?

Octopus merge merge only **non-conflicting** sources, but a lot of branches with guaranteed disjoint changes is ususal case from real-world

Answer (score 2):

With octopus merge you get only a single merge commit instead of several. Some people care a lot about the version history and find a lot of merge commits distracting.